# Page numbers in cumulative dissertation

Tags: thesis

I am writing a cumulative dissertation. In the main file I have an introduction and summaries of the publications. The pages all include page numbers. The publications I include into the main file however already have page numbers. What is the correct way to handle this? Right now I'm not showing the pager numbers of the main file when a publication is shown.

Answer (score 1):

In case you write your thesis with LaTeX, you may comfortably include external .pdf files (e.g., the .pdf of the publisher's version of your publication, preprints, etc.) with the usepackage [pdfpages](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).  From there, you may reference them easily, e.g., in the table of contents, because if not set to `fitpaper` the outer page counting of your thesis still will be intelligible on these pages. A gentle discern between the "normal pages" and these including your publication is to enable a fine frame on the later.  Test it with other packages already in use, and once you have a minimal example in hand ask your supervisor if s/he is fine with it.

For papers submitted but not yet "in print", you may use a template [like this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cumulative-dissertation-template/rdwdbhmwfyyc) of those by the journal as a preview.